# Question in the definition of curvature

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

$$K = \Bigg|\frac{dT}{ds}\Bigg| = \Bigg|\frac{\frac{dT}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}\Bigg|$$

where $T$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve and $s$ is arc lenght.

I don't know why that relationship is True in infinitesimals, in algebra I know the ratio $\frac{1}{dt}$ both in the numerator and the denominator is one but I am not sure how that works in infinitesimal and with an absolute value

Comment: Did you study the Chain Rule in your Calculus class (single variable)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes, I see your idea but It should not be? $\frac{dT}{dt}dt$ dt on the right cancels with dt in the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $s=s(t)$ and $T=T(s)=T(s(t))$. 
Applying the chain rule you get $\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{dT}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}$ and then divide by $\frac{ds}{dt}$ to obtain your equality.

Comment: is  my approach in the comments also correct?

Comment: No, because $\frac{ds}{dt}$  (and similarly the others) are not fractions but just a notation for the derivative of the function $s$ with respect to the variable $t$ (see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio#:~:text=%24%5Cboldsymbol%7B%5Cdfrac%7Bdy,notation%20of%20the%20derivative%20(c. )